# How correctly to register namespace and id in the data scheme?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I registered the id and namespace in the data schema and after that the releationships stopped working. How to fix it?

```
// Fiddle.model.User
schema: {
    id: 'fiddle',
    namespace: "Fiddle.model",
    ...
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22pc

Here's the error message:
VM775 app.js: 13 Uncaught TypeError: user.setAddress is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You need to add namespace and id in one model and extend that model.
Fiddle :https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22rm

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.model.Address', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
      schema: {

        // I registered the id and namespace in the data schema and after 
        // that the releationships stopped working.
        id: 'fiddle',
        namespace: "Fiddle.model",

        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'Users.json',
            reader: {
                rootProperty: 'result.ResultItems'
            }
        }
    },
    fields: [{
        name: 'street',
        type: 'string'
    }]
});
Ext.define('Fiddle.model.User', {
    extend: 'Fiddle.model.Address',

    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'name',
        type: 'string'
    }],
    hasOne: {
        role: 'address',
        association: "MassOperationTypeBySendMassNotificationsRequest",
        type: 'Fiddle.model.Address',
        reader: {
            rootProperty: 'address'
        },
        inverse: { role: "sendMassNotificationsRequest" }
    },
    hasMany: [{
        type: 'Fiddle.model.Order',
        role: 'orderList',
        reader: {
            rootProperty: 'OrderList'
        },
        inverse: {
            role: 'user'
        }
    }]
});
```